# Javascript Chrome profiler granularity - Go deeper

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, google-chrome, profiler

I'm currently debugging an Angular (JS) based app. I have **some speed issue** on runtime (client side) and want to analyze why.

I use the **Devtool profiler** from Chrome. I can see that some **Events** (i.e. keypress, blur) **took a lot of time** (see screenshot below).

[image]

Now I **would like to go deeper** and know which **source code contains these event listeners** and cause my application to slow down like this.

For information, the app is very slow when I write text in input, and when I focus/blur from my input; I know that some watchers could cause the slow down, but I'm not sure.

Hope deeper profiler analysis could help me !

**--- Edit 25 feb 2020 ---**

I think my problem is linked to digest cycle (apply/digest, etc).
I found this plugin : [digest-hud](https://github.com/pkaminski/digest-hud). After several tries, it seems that a binding (which is used in a lot of components) called "source" is taking all digest resource :

[image]

Comment: on a main thread you got selected on your image, just look left on the bottom what took longest time (in this case activity `ha`) and just click the link on right side to take you to that code that takes lot of time.. that task I think is some setTimeOut of 1500ms and kill it and hook with events

Comment: I tried to access to sources of ha activity. The problem is that Devtools gave me that "Could not load content for http://(...)/angular.js : HTTP status code: 404". It looks like a map source file problem, still not resolved that (new) issue to see what is that ha activity more precisely. Not sure about a setTimeOut problem.

Comment: yeah, that is map issue and that should give you to the root of `ha` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digest-hud was really helpful. I cannot find a way to know exactly how to find `ha` function initial calls on callstack. Like Kresimir Pendic said, probably a map issue.

But I found a lot of binding/watcher with `source` and one of them was called every single event of focus/blur/tipping. So I removed it, find an other way to signal changes within input and it works.

So don't hesitate to check with Digest-hud (disclaimer, I'm not releated in any way with Digest-hud developer(s)) if you have some performance issue with your AngularJS app, it'll give you some hints to solve the problem.